# jsp redirect error from java class

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee

forum members

I am stuck with problem and I need your help to get it solved soon.

Actually I am trying to open the JSP from my JAVA class.

**below is the code I am using to forward to my desired JSP page**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login/GetLoginCheck.action")
    public void sitemap (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)  throws Exception {
        try {
            System.out.println("QUERY TO GET LOGIN");
            //response.sendRedirect(response.encodeRedirectURL("../index.jsp"));
            request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").forward(request, response);
            return;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return;
        }
    }
```

no doubt the below code executes. **But after the code executes instead of forwarding to the jsp page it just show's me the code of index.jsp on my firebug console**

below is the image of my firebug console.
[image]

not able to understand why its not redirecting to my index.jsp page.

**please suggest me some solution to make my work done as soon as I can.**

Comment: @sha what do you didn't understand in my question ??? why did you vote negative me ??

Comment: Because it's kind of rude... "make my work done as soon as I can"...

Comment: @sha I am so sorry for being rude. I will keep that in mind

Comment: @sha I am having the same problem. Actually in the firebug console I am getting the page I want to open. What's the problem why my page is not being loaded freshly with the request page?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should simply use `response.sendRedirect("/index.jsp")`. Note that `../index.jsp` is not a valid URL for redirection based on the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendRedirect%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: you haven't seen that line is commented out by me ?? I am getting the index.jsp on my firebug console, but the page didn't get opened.. Did you understand my question ??

Comment: Now, I really doubt it. Do you deliberately use `forward` instead of `sendRedirect` but still mentioned _"not redirecting"_ in the last sentence of your question? Could there be some exception that you ignore?

Comment: please see the above answer and try to help me out to solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

In spring you have to use like this. more info [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html)

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login/GetLoginCheck.action")
    public String sitemap (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)  throws Exception {
        try {
            System.out.println("QUERY TO GET LOGIN");
            return "index";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return;
        }
    }
```

add this in your `dispatcher-servlet.xml`

```
<bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/jsps/</value> 
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Comment: when I use above code I get the 404 error. and in the HTML tab of firebug it shows me that **/ResourceMgt/WEB-INF/index.jsp** not found. Actually the page is located not in the WEB-INF folder its in the WebContent folder. So please suggest me how can I specify the custom jsp folder path in that.

Comment: Please include your bean configuration of Spring for `ViewResolver` in the description of your question. You can use this [reference](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/view.html) for custom JSP folder configuration.

Comment: just change /WEB-INF/jsps to /

Comment: @RameshK thanks for your response but the jsp page comes to my firebug console, but the jsp page didn't get loaded in the browser. I changed everything as you said.